# <p:selectOneMenu> onChange event doesn't reload form

Tags: events, jsf-2, primefaces, onchange

I trying to use the onChange event of selectOneMenu, but it doesn't work and the form is not reloaded bye the data chosen when I add onChange attribue.

Can someone tell me how can I handle the onChange event of ?

Here is my view:

```
<p:panel id="cubeId" header="Cube" widgetVar="toggleable>
<h:form id="CubeIdForm">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel value="Cube Name: "></p:outputLabel>
    <p:inputText value="#{cubeMan.cub.name_cube}"></p:inputText>
        <p:outputLabel value="Description: "></p:outputLabel>
    <p:inputText value="#{cubeMan.cub.description_cube}"></p:inputText>
        <p:outputLabel value="Caption: "></p:outputLabel>
    <p:inputText value="#{cubeMan.cub.caption_cube}"></p:inputText>
        <p:outputLabel value="Cache: "></p:outputLabel>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cubeMan.cub.cache}"></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <p:outputLabel value="Enabled : "></p:outputLabel>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cubeMan.cub.enabled}"
        label="Activate Cube"></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <p:outputLabel value="Visible : "></p:outputLabel>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cubeMan.cub.visible}"></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<p:outputLabel value="Select Column: " />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{cubeMan.name_cube}" id="cat">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Column" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{cubeMan.getColumnName()}" />

    </p:selectOneMenu>
<p:outputLabel value="Select Cube: " />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{cubeMan.name_cube}" id="cub">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Cube" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{cubeMan.AllCubs()}" />
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{cubeMan.dUpdateCube}" update="@this" />

</p:selectOneMenu>
</p:panelGrid>
<p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{cubeMan.makeCube()}" update="@form">
<p:commandButton action="#{cubeMan.handleCube()}" /></p:commandButton>

                            </h:form>

                        </p:panel>
```

And here is the  method in a request scoped bean:

```
public void dUpdateCube(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){

    cubeService.update_cube(cub);

}

public void handleCube() {  
    cubeService.update_cube(cub);
}
```

When I change the menu, however, nothing is been printed.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about the `selectOneMenu` with `id="cub"`.
You have to change the value of `update` of the `p:ajax`-element. With your current setting nothing gets updated. Try the following to update the whole form:

```
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{cubeMan.dUpdateCube}" update="@form" />
```

Comment: the problem i can't make a methode that can reload a form when we chose a selectItem in SelectIneMenu can you give me some example plz

Comment: the real problem is that i'm not sure that the method "dUpdateCube" it's the right one to reload select object into my form

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what your problem exactly is.

Comment: my problem is that i have a method AllCubs() that return a list of cube (object) and in the selectonemenu when i chose a object and select it i think taht i should have other method that will take that object and reload it in the form